# Bootstrap not loaded in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, react-multi-carousel

I am trying to make simple NextJs Application where I included bootstrap.

**Package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",         <----------------------------
    "next": "^10.0.3",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.5.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.1"
  },
```

**next.config.js:**

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withSass(withCss({
  webpack (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          publicPath: './',
          outputPath: 'static/',
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    });

    return config
  },
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }
}));
```

**pages/_app.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
import "../styles/styles.scss";

export default class ClnUi extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  }
}
```

**pages/index.tsx:**

```
    const Home = () => (
       <div class="container">
         This is a container div..
       </div>
    )

   export default Home;
```

I have made the import in `_app.tsx` and used inside `index.tsx` but this works perfectly fine in localhost but **only not in deployed vercel app**. `(projectname.vercel.app)` ..

Could you please kindly help me in figure out what I am doing wrong with my code above that causes the bootstrap css not loading in production environment alone?

But this css import `import "../styles/styles.scss";` has been working fine in both environments.

Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Maybe this can be useful for you https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

add this import statement on top of your _app.js file or in next 13 in top of your layout.js file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; // Import bootstrap CSS
```

worked for me.